# How to detect a click on an already selected tab in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

My question has been answered several times when it's a `TabActivity` with `tabWidgets`. But I couldn't find anything about the relativly new `TabLayout` view.

It's quite simple, like facebook, I want a tap on an already selected tab to get my list to scroll up til its beggining. but I can't figure out where to put my listener.

I tried on the `TabLayout` itself, `mTabLayout.getChildAt()` and on `TabLayout.getTabAt().getCustomView()`.

---

EDIT : Correction :
As CommonsWare mentionned in the comment of its answer, I had to rewrite the behaviour of "onTabSelected".

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
}

mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if (tab.getPosition() == PAGE_FEED) {
                ((PagerNewsFeedFragment) mViewPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(PAGE_FEED)).scrollToTop();
            }
    }
});
```

---

Thanks !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on spending ~10 seconds reading the documentation... call [`setOnTabSelectedListener()` on the `TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)). Pass in an `OnTabSelectedListener` implementation. Your event callback method [is `onTabReselected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html#onTabReselected%28android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.Tab%29).

Comment: yeah.. maybe that's why there is no stackoverflow about it. Doesn't work for me thought, I can't trigger the event. I'll post my code

Comment: It was due to ordering of my code lines. I don't know why but it doesn't work if ```setupWithViewPager``` is called after setting the listener

Comment: @RenaudFavier: The one concrete subclass of `OnTabSelectedListener` is `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`. Calling `setupWithViewPager()` probably replaces your own listener. You'll need to work out how best to handle the event you want and also have `ViewPager` integration.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but I don't understand your last sentence : "You'll need to work out how best to handle the event you want and also have ViewPager integration"

Comment: @RenaudFavier: I would assume that `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` is doing something useful, such as switching the `ViewPager` current item based on tab selections. Presumably, you still want that behavior. You *also* want to know when a tab is reselected. You'll have to figure out how to blend those two. It may be a matter of extending `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` yourself and tying it to your `ViewPager`. I haven't tried this, so I don't have an exact recipe for you.

Comment: well, you're right, the tab initial behaviour is lost. But what did they do beside switching tabs ? I just have to rewrite this part i guess

Comment: Try using addOnTabSelectedListener instead to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

To not lose the default behaviour use it like this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findById(this, R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        // Scroll to top or whatever
    }
});
```